# Cannot swap unique value on two rows with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unique-constraint

I'm trying to swap the value in a unique column for two (or more rows). For example:

*Before update:*

- Row 1 = 1
- Row 2 = 2

*After update:*

- Row 1 = 2
- Row 2 = 1

I'm using Entity Framework. These changes take place on a single commit for the same context. However, I always get a unique constrain violation when I attempt this update. Is EF not using a transaction?

For completeness, here is a snippet of my table design:

```
[FeeSchemeId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[SortPosition] INT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (FeeSchemeId, SortPosition)
```

I'm trying to update the 'SortPosition' column. The code is a bit complex to display here, but I can assure you that it is the same context with a single final commit. The error is only thrown when EF tries to write to the database.

**UPDATE:**

-
<del>Using SQL Server Profiler I can see that EF is running separate UPDATE for each affected row. Should EF not be using a single transaction for one call to SaveChanges()?</del>
-

**UPDATE 2:**

Turns out EF is using a single transaction after all. SQL Profiler was filtering it out.

Comment: "Is EF not using a transaction?" - that depends on what type of query you're running ([see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx#default)). Assuming it's an UPDATE query (which this should be), it's supposed to wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: You might have to make one of the keys nullable, or remove and reinsert the rows (assuming this is just a join table).

Comment: According to the SQL profiler. EF is running two separate statements for the update of the two rows.

Comment: Can you show a stripped-down version of the LINQ query? Also, even if "two separate statements" are executed, the transaction is on the **connection**, so those two queries will be rolled back together when the exception occurs.

Comment: @TiesonT. I can see that it is running separate statements by using a similar operation that does not make any changes to the UNIQUE column.

Comment: Scratch that. SQL Profiler was filtering out transaction statements.

Comment: Isn't FeeSchemeId meant to be a GUID given that it is a UniqueIdentifier

Comment: Yes, FeeSchemeId is a Guid, but I'm conflicting on SortPosition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with 2 statements also with SQL Server. You need to use a third value

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE MyTable Set Id = 200 where Id = 1;
UPDATE MyTable Set Id = 1 where Id = 2;
UPDATE MyTable Set Id = 2 where Id = 200;
COMMIT;
```

BTW, SQL Server profiler shows BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT statements

Comment: SQL Server Profiler only includes TRANSACTION statements explicitly. They are not included by default.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In your case you could expect that it worked if EF generates the 2 update statements inside an explicit transaction so SQL Server Profiler should show it. But also inside the same transaction SQL Server does not work...

Comment: Looks like you're right. I anticipated that because all the changes were completed during a transaction that SQL Server would check constraints against the overall effect rather than on individual statements.

Comment: SQL does not disable constraints during transactions... This is a common misconception. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974731/does-sql-server-allow-constraint-violations-in-a-transaction-as-long-as-its-not

Comment: I don't think this is true, I can swap two unique values with a single statement in TSQL. (well ok, maybe you can't do it with 2 statements because inbetween things would be invalid, but you can do it with 1 statement.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative trick I have used which doesn't rely on temporary values (which themselves risk violating uniqueness) is to issue a single UPDATE as in:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ID = case when id = 1 then 2 else 1 end
WHERE ID in (1, 2)
```

Unfortunately EF is not smart enough to generate those type of statements by itself.

Comment: yes, this works, and you can't seem to do it through EF. problem is, if you're testing you can't send raw SQL to a mock database.